# AWS best practices for allocating VMs to processes

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, virtual-machine, scalability, distributed-computing

What is the best practice to allocate EC2 VMs for a multi-tier web application. 
I have the following processes

- Node.js app for web-server
- Apache Kafka and Storm for backend. (or consider any middleware framework for that matter)
- Elasticsearch for storage
- Zookeeper for co-ordination

Should I put each of the above in its own VM so that its easy to scale and maintain? Is that how it should be done? 
What other approaches do people follow so I can make efficient use of the VMs?

Thank you

Comment: Typically yes, you'd see these as separate "tiers" on their own VMs. No one can reliably answer this for you, though, as your system may have unique/unusual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In a production deployment of multi-tier application, it's good practice to deploy each tier on separate VMs. However, depending on specific resource requirements of each component/tier like cpu, memory, disk, bandwidth usage etc., you may allocate different EC2 instance types for different component. It will make the efficient use of EC2 instance resources suiting each component.